# Ruby on Rails run task once a day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to execute a method in ruby (2.2) on rails (4.2) once a day, and am running windows 10 but will be uploading to Elastic Beanstalk in a Linux environment and as such can't use an OS specific scheduler like cron.  This rules out wheneverizer and the few other ways I can think of to go about doing this.  Is there any non-platform specific ways I can do this?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Just Google it you will find lots of tools available https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your task is to be performed in the background you could use [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) and [sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) to perform your task

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby based scheduler [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) which is (potentially) cross-platform.

> Clockwork is a cron replacement. It runs as a lightweight, long-running Ruby process which sits alongside your web processes (Mongrel/Thin) and your worker processes (DJ/Resque/Minion/Stalker) to schedule recurring work at particular times or dates. For example, refreshing feeds on an hourly basis, or send reminder emails on a nightly basis, or generating invoices once a month on the 1st.